# Is this sentence correct -?

Tags: sentence-construction, grammaticality

Please tell me if

> "... Some of the objects can be classified as musical instruments while some cannot".

Is Correct ?

Or would

> "... Some of the objects can be classified as musical instruments while some are not".

be better.

Thanks.

Comment: What is your own opinion? Please expand your question telling which of the two sentences you consider to be more correct, and why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose that it would be better to use Cannot, provided that Can has been used previously in the sentence. **Can be and cannot be** talk about the possibility of something, whereas, **are not** will make it definite. Completing the sentences may help you understand it better:

> Some of the objects **can be** classified as musical instruments while some **cannot be** classified.
>   Some of the objects **can be** classified as musical instruments while some **are not** classified.

Comment: I think we may also say "while some not" or "while others not".

Comment: "While others not" is a good option. What phrase should be used depends on what the readers would like. Some may please with "while some not", others with "cannot". This decision is personal to the writer.

Comment: It would be a good idea to familiarize yourself with the basic rules of this site.  We discourage "proofreading" questions (and answering those questions) because they have little utility to other English learners.  Instead please encourage the person asking the question to add more detail, explain what general principle they find confusing, and describe any research they've already done.

Comment: I would surely take note of it for future.

Comment: Since a beginner to this site, I am facing problem understanding what Proof Reading is. It would be kind of you to shed some light on the same.